# Reading ListView Image from SQL

Tags: c#, listview, imagelist

I use the following code to get movie covers from **SQL** and show them with their titles in a **Large Icon ListView Control**. I changed the view property to Large Icon. However, I can not see **covers** in the list. any idea?

```
        public ArchiveDataSetTableAdapters.MoviesTableAdapter movie_adap = new                    ArchiveDataSetTableAdapters.MoviesTableAdapter();
        ArchiveDataSet.MoviesDataTable temp_table = new ArchiveDataSet.MoviesDataTable();
        movie_adap.Fill(temp_table);
        if (temp_table.Count != 0)
        {
            ImageList ImageListLarge = new ImageList();

            for (int i = 0; i < temp_table.Count; i++)
            {
                Image cover = Properties.Resources.no_cover;
                try
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(temp_table[i].Cover);
                    cover = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
                catch { }
                ImageListLarge.Images.Add(cover);
                list_movies.Items.Add(temp_table[i].Title);
            }
            list_movies.LargeImageList = ImageListLarge;
            list_movies.TileSize = ImageListLarge.Images[0].Size;
        }
```

ListView is in a Winform and when I debug my app, I can see that images are loaded successfully in LargeImageList. But they dont show up in my listview

Comment: There isn't really enough information to answer your question.  What do you mean when you say you, `cannot see covers in the list`?  Are you trying to render this to a web page and the image is not rendering?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: sorry. No its in a Winform. I am not sure is it a render problem or reading problem. when I debug it, I can see all ImageLists have read the covers. But my ImageList does not show them

Comment: Ahh, I'm a web guy so I will bow out at this point.  Good luck :)